# Expectation and Variance of $X/(X+Y+Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expectation, variance

I feel like this might be really hard but I'm not sure. If you get this, you just might be a genius..

$X \sim \mathcal N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$,
$Y \sim \mathcal N(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$,
$Z \sim \mathcal N(\mu_3,\sigma_3)$

They are independent! Seems easy so far, right?

You tell me, is this easy?

> Compute
>   $$\mathbb E\left[\frac{X}{X+Y+Z}\right]$$
>   and
>   $$\operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{X}{X+Y+Z}\right].$$

Edit:

As someone in the comments pointed out this quantity is not defined. What about if I say:

$0<X<1$,
$0<Y<1$,
$0<Z<1$

So that the p.d.f.s of X,Y, and Z are divided by

$\Phi(1-\mu_1/\sigma_1)-\Phi(-\mu_1/\sigma_1),\Phi(1-\mu_2/\sigma_2)-\Phi(-\mu_2/\sigma_2),\Phi(1-\mu_3/\sigma_3)-\Phi(-\mu_3/\sigma_3)$, respectively (to make the sums under the curves 1 - did I do that right?).

Sorry if this is a ridiculous question.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Neither is defined.

Comment: good point @A.S.

Comment: Answer the question that should have been asked instead? The one where you cut off and get some distributions on some bounded intervals on the positive real axis?

Comment: ok.. not quite sure if i'll do it perfectly but i'll give it a shot thanks

Comment: I gave it my all. Sorry if it's not quite right or if it doesn't make sense at all. Tired, need rest..

Comment: I was interested in implementing this calculation so I just simulated normal random variables and calculated the means and variance of the quantities desired..